# Restoration identifier is not available on ios version prior to 6.0 warning

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, background-process, multitasking

I am using xcode 5,ios 7.When i run a code i get this warning ,eventhough the code is runnig.I went through developer.apple.com and found out this is something regarding restoration of app after coming from background to foreground.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html

But how to remove this ?

Comment: set your deployment target greater than or equal to 6.0

Comment: Thanks bro.But warning disappears with deployment target greater than or equal to  6.1,not with 6.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Warning tells you that property restorationIdentifier in `UIViewController` class is not available in iOS < 6.0. To fix this, set your deployment target to iOS >= 6.0 or don't use that property in your project.

Comment: There was also a warning PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in l4224 from /Users/interaxisnetworks/Downloads/iOSSample/PortSIPLib.framework/PortSIPLib(PortSIPLib). To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie